# Why setState does not change value?

Tags: reactjs

Why is below code not working?
It returns false even when I set inverted to true;
it also logs hit so it does reach.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ComponentProps } from 'react';

import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

type Props = {
} & ComponentProps<'div'>;

export function HeaderMaster({
  ...props
}: Props) {
  const [inverted, setInverted] = useState(false);
  const history = useHistory() 

   useEffect(() => {
    setInverted(true); // this does work
      history.listen((location) => { 
        console.log(location.pathname);
         if (location.pathname === '/bestellen') {
           setInverted(true); // this does not
           console.log('hit');
         }
         else {
          setInverted(false);
         }
      }) 

   },[history]);

   useEffect(() => {
    console.log(inverted);
  },[inverted]) 

  return (
    <>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: the component may get unmounted once the location changes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that can you explain more

Comment: Do you have any debugging details? Can you provide a more complete component example? Could you try reproducing this into a *running* codesandbox?

Comment: There is not much to add. I also testen setInverted outside of the listener and that does work

Comment: @RaymondtheDeveloper so you have this listener on history inside a component.. which will stay mounted as long as you are on the current location.. you change the location, which may lead to current component getting unmounted.. hence the useEffect on inverted doesn't trigger.. that's my best guess with given code

Comment: @tanmay you are correct I removed the whole listener and put the if else outside. That does work. I got that code from a tutorial not sure why he did it like this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example how this component is used? What is rendering it?

Comment: I got it from this tutorial: https://help.mouseflow.com/en/articles/4310818-tracking-url-changes-with-react

But it's solved already thanks