# Why does setState(null) not change the state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to open and close my Material UI `<Menu />` by using React's setState hook. I used [this sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-qwnds?file=/demo.js) as an example. My implementation doesn't seem to close the menu however.

Opening it works fine (using `setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)`), but closing it using `setAnchorEl(null)` does not somehow. The function `handleClose()` runs (the `console.log()` prints fine), but the value of `anchorEl` does not change. I checked this using the `useEffect()` hook, which prints null on initialization, the `<li>` element when opening and nothing when trying to close.

I already tried using `let` instead of `const` for the (`set`)`anchorEl` and `isProfileMenuOpen` definition, but this doesn't work. I also checked out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619083/why-setstate-does-not-change-value), but my `<MenuAppBar />` component is not being unmounted as far as I can see (it's rendered at the root unconditionally).

I must be overlooking some detail. Can anybody spot it below?

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const { ClickAwayListener, Menu, MenuItem, IconButton } = MaterialUI;

function MenuAppBar(props) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const isProfileMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

  // For debugging purposes:
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(anchorEl);
  }, [anchorEl]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log("Closing menu"); // This prints, so function runs
    setAnchorEl(null); // This doesn't seem to set anchorEl to null
  };

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget); // This does work
  }

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5B089" }}
        />
        <Menu
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={isProfileMenuOpen}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </MenuItem>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MenuAppBar />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: That's the downside of giving you a minimal reproducible example ;). Any idea what could generate noise setting state in react?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've thrown it in a snippet for you. Some bizarre behaviour indeed.

Comment: @samthecodingman - Thanks, hopefully the OP appreciates it as well. It's just that `setAnchorEl` is getting called a second time, after the call setting `null`, putting the same `li` back in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that after `handleClose` is called, `handleProfileMenuOpen` is called again. So you end up with two calls to `setAnchorEl` during the same click event, so React only re-renders the component once — with it set to what `handleProfileMenuOpen` set it to (or not at all if it was the same `li`, as it is in the Stack Snippet).

If you stop the event from propagating, it prevents the `handleProfileMenuOpen` call:

```
const handleClose = (event) => {
    console.log("Closing menu");
    setAnchorEl(null);
    event.stopPropagation(); // <=====
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const { ClickAwayListener, Menu, MenuItem, IconButton } = MaterialUI;

function MenuAppBar(props) {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const isProfileMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
  
  console.log(anchorEl);

  const handleClose = (event) => {
    console.log("Closing menu"); // This prints, so function runs
    setAnchorEl(null); // This doesn't seem to set anchorEl to null
    event.stopPropagation();
  };

  const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
    console.log("Opening menu");
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget); // This does work
  }

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClose}>
      <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
        <IconButton
          style={{ backgroundColor: "#F5B089" }}
        />
        <Menu
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={isProfileMenuOpen}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </MenuItem>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MenuAppBar />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

Side note: If you want to see `anchorEl` changing as the component is rerendered, there's no need for a `useEffect` call, just log it at the top level of your component function (or put a breakpoint on the `const [anchorEl ...` line). Remember that the component function is called each time the component is rendered, so that will always show you the up-to-date version of `anchorEl`.